# How to select all data from table but only display one row at a time through php

Tags: php, sql

So I have a table in sql. It's basically a inspection report. I've created the form it works great. Submits. Now I want to create a way to call upon an individual report from the table, and display it in a table on php. 
The Below code works perfectly for displaying my information (there is a lot more than 3 colums, just using 3 as an example). The problem is I want to only display one inspection report at time basically, and perhaps even have create a search based on date submitted. The below code is the only way I know how to select ALL the table.

```
<?php 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inspection ORDER BY name");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID #</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>inspection #</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Inspection #'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

This works great, just need to know how to better use it for my search. Keep in mind i'm doing this through php for an end user so that he could perhaps just see a page that gives him all dates of inspections and click on the one and it pulls all data and shows up.

Comment: If you're only gonna display one row, then why do you want to select _all_ the data in the table? Why not just select the row you want to display?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you pick PDO [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM inspection WHERE `<column>` `<operator>` `<value>`

The `<value>` can come from a variety of places: dropdown, where the end user selects a value from the options, or an input field where the end user inputs what they want. Similarly you can filter for many other options by adding more clauses to the where statement.

As an addition to your given example, if you want to select only inspections where Name is Bob, you can do:

SELECT * FROM inspections WHERE Name = 'Bob'

if you want the Name to be "generic", defined by the end user, give them a input field.

**search.php**

```
<form action="result.php" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="Name" />
</form>
```

**result.php**

```
SELECT * FROM inspections WHERE Name = $_GET['Name']
```

The above is a **VERY** rough idea, but it should be a good starting point. Like @Matt added you can do it server side or client side.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this: pagination with server-side processing of the pages, or javascript (jquery) pagination.

I have done both in the past and found that jQuery datatables are an excellent tool - you print out all the records to the page, then jQuery takes over and displays them in paged format. http://datatables.net/

To do this with server-side pagination, you would need to keep track of the number of records and the current record you're on. Then you'll have to modify your SQL statement to something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM inspection ORDER BY name LIMIT $page, 1
```

And pass $page through each time you navigate forward/backwards in the table. It's pretty code-intensive, but a good exercise if you're looking for one.

Finally, if you want to search within a date range you can further modify your query:

```
SELECT * FROM inspection 
WHERE date BETWEEN [some start date] AND [some end date] 
ORDER BY name LIMIT $page, 1
```